# Renaming mysql dumpfile to current date and then gzip it

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm writing a bash script to do a mysqldump. But I need to add the date dynamically.

The script would be run from a cronjob everyday and it should dump the SQL files corresponding with the date. Like: 12.sql, 13.sql, etc.

Here's the mysql dump code:

```
`mysqldump -hHOST -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME TABLENAME > dump.sql`
```

Instead of the dump.sql I need to add the date dynamically and then gzip it. How do I do it?
I'm a total n00b at bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fetch the current date in a custom format with the `date` command and save it into a variable. Later you can use its value to name the dump file. Compression can be evaluated with the `gzip` command. It will be replace the uncompressed file, but you can keep that with the `-c` option if you would like.

```
now=`date +"%m_%d_%Y"`
mysqldump -hHOST -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME TABLENAME > dump_$now.sql
gzip  dump_$now.sql
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But I can't seem to download that file via FTP. For for reason the Filetype keeps showing as "File"

But if I do a normal dump, I'm able to download it.

Comment: You should explain how a certain file type prevents you from downloading the file.